# Determine if an executable (or library) is 32 or 64 bit

Tags: macos, binary, osx-snow-leopard

Is it possible to get information about any binary on OS X to determine if it's a 32 bit or 64 bit binary?

I played with the 'otool' command but can't find this kind of information.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use the `file` command instead of `otool`. It will list all the architectures in the binary. On Intel Macs i386 is 32 bit and x86_64 is 64 bit.

Comment: Great ! shame on me for not finding this :)

Comment: `lipo -info` is more useful for determining the architecture on static libraries.

Comment: `file /path/to/your/binaryFile` on macOS 10.14 Mojave worked great for me on a large variety of executables, be it the executable within a .app bundle or printer drivers, plugins, etc.

Answer (score 11):

From Nicholas in a comment, `lipo -info` also works.  This is what you must use on static libraries, since `file` only displays "current ar archive random library."

Comment: The only problem with `lipo -info` is that it errs on non-binary executable files. For example, if you're running GNU `find` like this: `gfind /opt/local/bin -executable -exec lipo -info "{}" \;`, you'll get errors on scripts. E.g. `fatal error: lipo: can't figure out the architecture type of: /opt/local/bin/hg` In such cases, `file` is a better command to use.