# How to detect if a Cocoa application is 32 bit or 64bit?

Tags: cocoa, macos

How to detect if a Cocoa application is  32 bit or 64bit ?

Comment: Are you trying to detect if your application is running in 64bit mode or are you trying to detect which platforms are supported in a binary?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine if an executable (or library) is 32 -or 64-bits (on OSX)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941825/determine-if-an-executable-or-library-is-32-or-64-bits-on-osx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Terminal, type

```
file ApplicationBinary
```

If it says `Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64`, then it is 64-bit, if it says `Mach-O executable i386` then it is 32-bit, etc.

Comment: Hi Kenny,

I tried this, it says /Applications/Address Book.app: directory 

I tried file /Applications/Address\ Book.app

Comment: Hi Kenny,
I should have tried 
file /Applications/Address\ Book.app/Contents/MacOS/Calico 
/a.app/Contents/MacOS/Address\ Book

It worked.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The /Applications/Address Book.app **is** a directory. To find the actual executable, you need to cd to /Applications/Address Book.app/Contents/MacOS and run the file command on the Address Book executable in that directory (eg. file "Address Book").