# Unable to use Boost in Xcode, keep getting "Undefined symbols for architecture" errors

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, cocoa, boost

I'm trying to include Boost in my Xcode project and it seems no matter what I do the project doesn't want to compile.

I get this error every time:

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

```
"boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record_view::public_data::destroy(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record_view::public_data const*)", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record::reset() in Logger.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_set::insert(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_name, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute const&)", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::basic_logger<char, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level>, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::single_thread_model>::add_attribute_unlocked(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_name const&, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute const&) in Logger.o
```

(Along with a bunch of others totally 108 errors.)

I've tried a lot to fix this, and read pretty much every question on StackOverflow that is relevant to this.

I *am* linking it in "Link Binary With Items", I've got `libboost_serialization.a` and `libboost_system.a` there (only things in that list).

After installing Boost manually with the `./b2` command, I dragged both of those files into the sidebar. Therefore, the files are in the same directory as my `.xcodeproj`.

Under `Library Search Paths`, I have `$(PROJECT_DIR)`, so it should be able to find them.

Am I compiling it with the wrong flags or something?

Comment: Are you sure you compiled your boost libraries for x86_64 and not just i386? How did you build boost?

Comment: I believe I ran these commands:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/8497667/998117 Should I try something else?

Comment: You should try and find out whether you built a x86_64 library and then you need to make sure that you link your project against libc++ instead of libstdc++, just as you did with boost.

Comment: How do I do the latter?

Comment: Click on your project in Xcode, then, in the filter box of the project properties, enter libc. It will show you a Setting named "C++ Standard Library" which you can then change.

Comment: Then when I try to build I get "clang: error: invalid deployment target for -stdlib=libc++ (requires OS X 10.7 or later)" and how do I figure out if my boost library is 64 bit or 32?

Comment: Use the file command: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207177/how-to-check-if-a-library-is-32bit-64bit-built-on-mac-os-x

Comment: "libboost_serialization.a: current ar archive random library"

Comment: I suppose the problem is that you linked boost against libc++ and link your program to libstdc++. Since you can't change your program to link against libc++ (assuming you don't want to set the deployment target to OX X 10.7), you have to rebuild boost and link it against libstdc++.

Comment: My program was linked to "Compiler Default" per that setting you mentioned. How would I go about rebuilding boost and linking it against libstdc++? Would I have to remove the current version somehow?

Comment: For linking boost against libstdc++, you could try running ./b2 clean and then ./b2 toolset=clang cxxflags="-stdlib=libstdc++" linkflags="-stdlib=libstdc++"

Comment: Then you can overwrite the boost .a libraries in your project directory with the newly built ones.

Comment: So it doesn't install anything at the system level I should be wary of? Just need to build new .a files in the `stage/lib` folder?

Comment: I don't know. If all else fails, you could try installing boost with macports or homebrew.

Comment: Just repeat what you did earlier: "After installing Boost manually with the ./b2 command, I dragged both of those files into the sidebar. "

Comment: Same error as last time unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry, then I don't know what else to do.

Comment: You may want to use this script https://gist.github.com/emersonxsu/7188a128c28485b2533e and create a framework. Read the starting comments in script carefully.

Answer (score 1):

This solved the problem for me:

Rather than adding `libboost_log-mt.*` to the ‘Link Binary With Libraries’ section under the ‘Build Phases’ tab, add a path to the *archive file* (i.e., the `.a`; dynamic library doesn't work) in ‘Other Linker Flags’ under the ‘Build Settings’ tab:

[Other Linker Flags under Build Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M73IQ.png)

I have no explanation for *why* this works; but I've noticed that this technique has worked for me in the past with other libraries ‘not linking’ as well.

Comment: Quite close, I managed to finally get my project built by using the .dylib version, not .a, of both libboost_log-mt and libboost_log_setup-mt on boost 1.72