# On OS X, how do I find out what architecture a shared lib is compiled for?

Tags: macos, unix, architecture

I need to know whether I compiled libjpeg for 32 or 64 bits architecture, but don't know how to find out, is there a command that will let me check?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine if an executable (or library) is 32 -or 64-bits (on OSX)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941825/determine-if-an-executable-or-library-is-32-or-64-bits-on-osx)

Answer (score 48):

just type `file libjpeg.dylib` and you'll get output like the following

```
libpoll.dylib: Mach-O universal binary with 3 architectures
libpoll.dylib (for architecture x86_64): Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
libpoll.dylib (for architecture i386): Mach-O dynamically linked shared library i386
libpoll.dylib (for architecture ppc7400): Mach-O dynamically linked shared library ppc
```

Answer (score 18):

The `file` command will work just fine. Alternatively, you can use 
`otool` to print the fat headers.

```
$ otool -vf /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
Fat headers
fat_magic FAT_MAGIC
nfat_arch 2
architecture ppc
    cputype CPU_TYPE_POWERPC
    cpusubtype CPU_SUBTYPE_POWERPC_ALL
    offset 4096
    size 2221800
    align 2^12 (4096)
architecture ppc64
    cputype CPU_TYPE_POWERPC64
    cpusubtype CPU_SUBTYPE_POWERPC64_ALL
    offset 2228224
    size 2169980
    align 2^12 (4096)
```

Answer (score 7):

Use the `file` command:

```
[mqudsi@iqudsi:Xcode/FSLogger]$ file ./original                   (07-31 02:53)
./original: Mach-O executable i386
```