# How can I check if a compiled binary is 32-bit or 64-bit?

Tags: macos

I have a Mac running Lion and I just downloaded latest version of apache. 
I did the usual things:

```
$./configure --prefix=/Users/daniels/Sandbox
$ make
$ make install
```

For what architecture is the httpd binary compiled? x86 or x64? Is there a way to find this?

What I am looking for is that I want to make a MAMP-like application and I want to compile Apache, PHP, and MySQL in such way that I can put them in a DMG file and then give it to other people and they can run it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine if an executable (or library) is 32 -or 64-bits (on OSX)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941825/determine-if-an-executable-or-library-is-32-or-64-bits-on-osx)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Check out the `file` command.

```
$ file /usr/bin/grep
/usr/bin/grep: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
/usr/bin/grep (for architecture x86_64):    Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
/usr/bin/grep (for architecture i386):  Mach-O executable i386
```

Answer (score 3):

The `lipo` binary also does this.

```
lipo -archs

$ lipo -archs 'Adobe Photoshop Lightroom 5'
x86_64 

lipo -info

$ lipo -info 'Adobe Photoshop Lightroom 5'
Non-fat file: Adobe Photoshop Lightroom 5 is architecture: x86_64
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to determine if the Apache is 32-bit or 64-bit is to execute the following in the global zone by using dtrace:

```
sudo dtrace -qn 'syscall::: /execname == "httpd"/ { ab = (curpsinfo->pr_dmodel == PR_MODEL_ILP32) ? "32-bit" : "64-bit" ; exit(0); } END { printf("Apache: %s",ab); }'
```