# Dumped i386 assembly code and recompile as PPC?

Tags: assembly, disassembly, i386, powerpc, otool

I used the Apple built-in "otool" command with "-Vvtd" switches to dump a Mach-O i386 binary, redirected to a .s file. I have tried unsuccessfully to use nasm and GAS assemblers to recompile the code on a PPC machine ("as"-binary in the i386 directory of gcc/darwin and "as"-binary in the ppc directory as well). The output reads something like:

```
some_topmost_label:
(__TEXT,__text) section
_default_pager:
00112000    pushl   %ebp
00112001    movl    %esp,%ebp
00112003    pushl   %edi
00112004    pushl   %esi
00112005    pushl   %ebx
00112006    subl    $0x3c,%esp
00112009    movl    _default_pager_internal_count,%ebx
0011200f    addl    _default_pager_external_count,%ebx
00112015    leal    0x00000004(,%ebx,4),%ebx
```

There is a data section as well, going like:

...

```
(__DATA,__data) section
00421000    02 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 00 40 00 00 28 64 65 66
```

...

```
00449bc0    50 00 3d 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00449bd0    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

...

I am intent on running the binary in Mac on PPC, hence the recompiling effort; I have tried removing the addresses in the leftmost column to make the syntax more "AT&T"-style, leaving them, etc. I DO NOT want to make any edits to the existing code structure (this is not exactly a reverse-engineering effort, per se, just some customization). However, if I have to do any editing, I would very much like it to be strictly for making the existing, unadulterated code for i386 run as is on PPC.

I will very much appreciate your help.

Regards

Comment: You can't run i386 code natively on ppc. You will need an emulator.

Comment: "Hint hint -- this code DOES processor emulation". I would like to please know whether these assembly commands..."pushl" "movl" etc. can form a runnable file with the right assembler on PPC. Thanks.

Comment: Besides, it's now source code as a .s file. So anything goes.

Comment: No, assembly is different for each architecture. Just because it's now a text file, doesn't mean it's in any way compatible with ppc. ppc does not even have `pushl` or `movl` or any of the registers of an i386.

Comment: You are talking about emulation here.  Emulation is not an easy thing to do :)

Comment: Yes, taking a look at the dump, it would be an utter mess without the original C to compile on PPC. THEN (I suppose) having the original C would be the solution....hmm....

Comment: The other option besides emulation is a decompiler. I wouldn't bet on it working. Decompiling is even more of a not-easy thing to do.

Comment: P.S. if it was this easy, we would have moved all the world's x86 programs to PPC instead of vice versa, so we could have a *nice* architecture now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decompilers can produce C files (as I have tried) which can be used to compile from source on a different architecture (which I have also tried). The experience was dicey at best. I'm still working on it and will likely still be for some time.

As an alternative, emulation can be implemented to run a binary/executable for i386 on ppc. This is a quick, but potentially less effective, route.

In addition, I feel it confirmed that assembly-to-assembly would be the most painful route as opposed to using the C programming language as an intermediate (by decompiling the i386 binary to C and recompiling the C on the target architecture).

In the case of decompiling: what if it produces a quarter-million lines of code? You may need a team :)

Answer (score 4):

In assembly language, every "statement" is an instruction that the processor can execute. The instructions are represented in a human-readable text format (if you're the right kind of human) but still, every instruction name (e.g. `movl`) and register (e.g. `%esp`) and memory reference (e.g. `0x00000004(,%ebx,4)`) that exists in assembly directly corresponds to an implementation detail of the processor.

So every processor really has its own assembly language. Dumping and re-assembling doesn't get you anywhere. Not even within a set of related processors - if you take some 32-bit x86 code that was compiled SSE3 optimizations enabled and dump it, you'll have assembly code with SSE3 instructions. Re-assembling it won't get you a program that can run on a slightly older x86-32 processor.

There might be a chance, if your executable is old enough, that it's a ["fat binary"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_binary). During the period when PPC and x86 Macs were both supported by Apple, they would pack the compiled PPC and x86 code together in a single file. Judging by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7471802/2404501) you can detect fat binaries with the `file` command.

But chances are you have to do a lot more work than you were expecting.

PPC doesn't have a `movl` instruction (or any other kind of `mov` - it handles loads and stores separately). It doesn't have a dedicated stack register like `%esp`, although `r1` is a safe bet. It doesn't have anything like the addressing mode in `0x00000004(,%ebx,4)` - that's a register being multiplied by 4 and then adding the constant 4 - in PPC you'll have to load the constant into a different register with one instruction, then shift (`*4` = `<<2`) the register in another instruction, then add those intermediate results together in a third instruction. This is not a matter of whether the instructions are written in "source form" or "binary form". It's a matter of the instructions in the original code *not existing at all* on the PPC.

Comment: OK, so I would have to sift manually through the code and reassemble it touch-and-go. Is this done in practice often? Or are there automated tools that can ease the transition (do architecture-rewriting automatically...?) I take from the above answer (which I've upvoted :) ) 1 instruction can equal 3 in some cases.

Comment: I don't know of any assembly-to-assembly translators. The decompilers, using C as an intermediate, are probably the closest thing to that, but I don't see any optimistic reviews of them. In any case you won't end up running "the same program". You'll have a new program built to act like the first one. Or you do the emulation - provide the original program a replica of the environment it was meant to run in.

Comment: The typical path would be to take a higher level language (like C, for example) and compile that down to the assembly.  It would be very rare and very painful to convert from one assembly to another.

Comment: @Everyone upvoting above: it should be made clear to newbies that ONLY if the `file` command gets output that the binary has the ppc archictecture, in addition to i386 and/or x86_64, is it the desired **fat binary** for the line of discussion here. The link above doesn't show that. For newbies: please see the answer below for a summary.